# Array Index Out Of Bounds In Char Array

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I am attempting to generate a gameboard as a 2D array of chars, the top layer of the array is displaying the char versions of ints(no problems there), however the code is throwing an error message, as displayed below.

```
java -classpath .:/run_dir/junit-4.12.jar:target/dependency/*

Main Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2
at Main.genVisual(Main.java:16)
at Main.main(Main.java:3)
```

Here is my code:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[][] hehe = genVisual(7, 2);
    }

    public static char[][] genVisual(int length, int height) {
        char[][] visual = new char[height][length];
        char character = ' ';
        for (int n = 0; n < height; n++) {
            for (int i = 0; n < length; n++) {
                if (n == 0) {
                    int w = i + 1;
                    character = (char) w;
                    visual[n][i] = character;
                } else {
                    visual[n][i] = 'x';
                }
            }
        }

        return visual;
    }
}
```

I have tried changing the values that control the list size in the `for` loop and have browsed this website for answers, however I do not see any issues with the program.

Comment: "*`for(int i = 0; n<length; n++){`*" - The `n` and the `n++` should most probably be an `i` and an `i++`.

Comment: that might be kind of an issue, thanks, im kinda dumb after a while.

Comment: Turing85 is correct.  Stepping through your code with a debugger would have helped you find this.

Comment: I am not knowledgeable on how to use a debugger.

Comment: The very best day to learn is today.

Comment: @Foehammer Which software do you use to code in Java?

Comment: Replit to code in java